# Xorg failed to start correctly

Tags: linux-mint, boot, xorg, crash

Overall I am not actually sure how I arrived here, but i changed the order of my drives as I wanted to add back one in that I had previously removed. Then i was presented with this error message which i have tried to follow and get to the bottom, but now I need your help (from people who know what they are doing)

So far I have removed xorg, reinstalled, reconfigured. Searched and tried to fix any other error that has popped up along the way. I have removed the monitors files, tbh everything I could think of to try and get this little guy working again :(

I am running 18.2 mint

[image]

Sadly here is the whole log for you guys:
https://pastebin.com/V4bGMjax

A teaser:

```
[    33.080] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[    33.080] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    33.080] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    33.080] Current Operating System: Linux hutber-min 4.11.0-14-generic #20~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 9 09:06:22 UTC 2017 x86_64
[    33.080] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.11.0-14-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro recovery nomodeset
[    33.080] Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:57:05PM
[    33.080] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    33.080] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    33.080]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    33.080] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    33.080] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Oct 23 23:31:12 2017
[    33.080] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    33.081] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    33.081] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    33.081] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    33.081] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    33.081] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    33.081] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    33.081] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    33.081] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    33.081] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    33.083] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    33.083]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    33.083] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    33.083]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    33.083] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    33.083]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    33.083] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    33.083]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    33.083] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    33.083]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    33.083] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    33.083] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    33.083] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    33.083] (II) Loader magic: 0x8fbb459dc0
[    33.083] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    33.083]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    33.083]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    33.083]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    33.083]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    33.083] (++) using VT number 7
```

Comment: 1) Did you perform a sanity reboot before rearranging your drives?  If not, the drive swap may not have caused the problem.  2) If so, did you try reinitializing udev?  Rearranging hardware might require this.  Not knowing whether or how you built the system originally, it's hard to tell what the most efficient recovery is, but if you can't easily back out, perhaps start with some of X11's monitor-probing tools.

Comment: Thanks Code Read :) You give me hope, so I am able to boot into my system via the recovery option, no problems. I have only tried really what I wrote in the question tbh. So I will now google monitor-probing tools and also the reinitialising of the udev(which i haven't heard of before) I have 5 internal drives and nothing else special about my system